# Is there a specific term for humourous repetition where the repeated thing is only funny through context?

Tags: humor

I've tried searching for terms relating to humourous repetition, but the only term I can find is "repetition". And that's absolutely fine, I don't mind referring to it as such if necessary, but I feel that this particular device is specific enough that it needs something more specific to describe it.

As an example, let's say someone makes a list of top 5 characters they don't like in World of Warcraft, and they say

> 1. Garrosh. 2. Garrosh. 3. Garrosh. 4. Garrosh. 5. Garrosh

The humour lies in the fact that Garrosh is a recognisably-terrible character to the majority of WoW players for several reasons. The repetition itself isn't funny, but the context of what is *being* repeated renders it humourous to people who understand the context.

Another example, from Alestorm's song "Mexico":

> The wenches they are plenty, the alcohol is free
>
> The party lasts all through the night and the alcohol is free

The humour lying in the fact that he's listing reasons the place he goes is fun and mentions the alcohol being free twice because, well, he's a pirate. Of course that's going to be a selling point worth mentioning more than once.

But other than repetition, does anyone know of a term that describes this kind of device?

Comment: [Blazing Saddles:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V7AmUV2wGIY) "Next! Qualifications?", "Rape, murder, arson, and rape", "You said rape twice", "I like rape".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yep, that's exactly the kind of thing I mean. :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers On a less topical note it's been a while since I was last on here, so it's nice to see you're still around. :)

Comment: Thanks for the memory! You've inspired me to go and see what I could find

Comment: Not sure if you remember me, I have a slightly less memorable username. XD Incidentally, how did you find that? I did try some searches but I didn't turn anything up.

Comment: I think you are asking for two _separate_ things in one. You're asking for  a word to describe humor through repetition, and then separately something to describe humor through context. And in some sense, much of humor is through context. Except for puns. They're awful all by themselves.

Comment: @Mitch It was more a word to describe humour through *contextual repetition* but I get your point. Fumblefingers found a word that works perfectly for my needs though.

Comment: @John: I started off by thinking "Crumbs! Here's me with a degree in Eng Lit, and I'm sure nobody ever thought to teach me the technical term for this!" Which kinda led me to thinking I might have been better educated if I'd been born 50 years later, and thus been able to benefit from Tony Blair's focus on education. That inspired me to google **rhetorical device "education education education"**. The rest, as they say, is history (like Tony Blair! :)

Comment: @JohnClifford I was just being pedantic. Yes, repetition is the important thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Wikipedia...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epizeuxis)

> In rhetoric, an **epizeuxis** is the repetition of a word or phrase in immediate succession, typically within the same sentence, for vehemence or emphasis. It is also called **diacope**.
> As a rhetorical device, epizeuxis is utilized to create an emotional appeal, thereby inspiring and motivating the audience. However, epizeuxis can also be used for comic effect.

Examples (with a nod to *another* rhetorical device - ["The Rule of Three"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(writing)#:%7E:text=The%20rule%20of%20three%20is,or%20effective%20than%20other%20numbers.)) include...

> [Top three factors to consider when buying property:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location,_Location,_Location)
> *Location, Location, Location.*

> [*Blazing Saddles* thug recruitment line:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V7AmUV2wGIY)
> *"Next! Qualifications?", "Rape, murder, arson, and rape", "You said rape twice", "I like rape!"*

> [Tony Blair's election-winning slogan:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1nkOPhl9ZS4&feature=youtu.be&t=31)
> *Education, Education, Education*

(Wikipedia doesn't *actually* include my second example. But I couldn't resist, since my top three all-time favourite movies are *Blazing Saddles*, *Blazing Saddles* and *Blazing Saddles* :)

Comment: You are the hero Gotham needs.

Comment: https://youtu.be/1nkOPhl9ZS4?t=31

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica: My Wankel engine obviously wasn't firing on all three cylinders when I wrote this! Third example duly included, ty. :)

Answer (score 0):

It’s called “comic torture.” You repeat something a few times because it’s funny. You keep repeating it until it’s not funny anymore. Then you KEEP repeating it until the repetition itself becomes so ridiculous, it’s funny again. The show “Family Guy” is famous for this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).